# Showing $ g(a)\;\inf_x \int_a^x f(t)dt \leq \int_{a}^b f(t)g(t)dt $ for $g$ monotonic decreasing and $g(b)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that if $f$, $g$ riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, $g$ monotonic decreasing and $g(b) = 0$, then:
> $$
> g(a)\;\inf_x \int_a^x f(t)dt \leq \int_{a}^b f(t)g(t)dt
> $$

Sorry, I am just so lost since I can't use the ordering of integral here since I don't know when f will be positive or negative. I've reduced it to:
$$
\int_{a}^b f(t)g(t)dt \geq \inf_x \int_a^x f(t)g(t)dt \geq g(a) \inf_x \int_a^x f(t)dt = (g(a)-g(b)) \inf_x \int_a^x f(t)dt
$$
with the 2nd inequality looking like something that's easier to prove and maybe involve some identity, intermediate value theorem or something, but I don't know

Comment: This is immediate from second MVT for integrals: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: is there a way to do this without proving second MVT?